# How to zoom with Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I have a large map in vectorgraphics, that I show in my custom view.
I move the map with the canvas.translate() function, so I don't need to recalculate all pathes of my lines again.

Is there any similar mechanism to achieve a zooming function? I would like to keep my paths with the values and zoom out and in, Or do I have to recalculate all points of my pathes from scratch.

Regards

Comment: embarrassing :-) Thanks a lot, so easy. How can I finish this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canvas.scale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float%29) will scale the canvas (zoom in/out).  Try performing the scale after you draw your paths.  If it does not work you'll need to recalculate the points.

Comment: np, semantics (zoom vs scale) can throw everyone off now and then