# Zoom and draw line on canvas and set canvas on origenal image

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, paint

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924062/android-zoom-image-and-draw-line-on-image-with-current-zoom) code for the drawing a line on canvas by zooming image its perfect one but I get stuck with that I can't get original image with drawn line on original image, in this code I get only cropped area of the image where I draw a line.

I want to do that make zoom image, draw a line on it and get original image with drawn line on perfect position on image.

would anybody help me for this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no "original image", ImageView uses Drawable concept, you can get it by calling `getDrawable()` method

Comment: @pskink whenever I save bitmap image from save method, I get only zoomed area with drawn line, I want drawn line with whole image.

Comment: this is because you shouldn't override onDraw method, you should use a custom Drawable and do your custom drawing there

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the reply, but I didn't get it, could you explain me more, how to do that?

Comment: see Drawable javadoc,  pay attention to the draw() method

Comment: Okay Thanks I will look in to this, but is there other option to draw line by finger by zooming image and save image as original image with that drawn line?